# Grohe Lady Lux Leaking

Tags: plumbing

The unit is 29 months old.  It is leaking down the inner mesh tube and directly into the cabinet area.  I replaced the cartridge but the leak continues.
Robert Brown

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I think the question is "how can I stop this from leaking?"

Comment: Apparently that's a single-handle kitchen faucet.

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/152838/grohe-ladylux-faucet-leaking-after-11-years?rq=1

Comment: Sounds like a disposable razor designed for women's legs,  @HotLicks...